# Unable to connect github to Aws Ec2 Instance using pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, repository, pipeline

I am trying to connect my aws account to Github using pipeline [error message one= an organization owner must install the Github app but i keep getting this error once its time to configure "an organization owner must install the Github app". I would need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct GitHub permissions to do it. Best asking whoever created or manages your Github Organization to sort it.